# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'

Tags: python-3.6, lamp, six

I am trying to setup `lamp server` on my `Fedora 27`. Referring this [site](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/fedora-how-tos/how-to-install-lamp-on-fedora-22.html), I am following every step, but running this command `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http`, here are the following errors I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/firewall-cmd", line 31, in <module>
    from firewall.client import FirewallClient, FirewallClientIPSetSettings, \
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firewall/client.py", line 29, in <module>
    import slip.dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slip/dbus/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import service
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slip/dbus/service.py", line 30, in <module>
    from six import with_metaclass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

I reinstalled `six` package, but still the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the six Python module installed. You can find it on 
[pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six)

To install it:

```
$ easy_install six
```

If you have pip installed you can run `$ pip install 'six'`

Comment: Are you sure it's the same python or the same python version that your command is using?

Comment: Yes @user3362334